# Custom validator with multiple components

Tags: validation, jsf

I have a large application form that the user has to fill in. It consists of several tables that are placed in their respective `<ui:include>`s. I have a custom validator that needs to validate multiple input fields located in different tables. Here's a simple version of how it looks:

### application_form.xhtml

```
<div class="tableContainer">
    <ui:include src="applications/edit/info1.xhtml"/>
    <ui:include src="applications/edit/info2.xhtml"/>
</div>
<h:commandButton id="validateButton">
    <a4j:ajax oncomplete="if (#{!facesContext.validationFailed})displayModal()"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

### info1.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
    <rich:dataTable id="info1">
        <rich:columnGroup>
            <rich:column>
                inputField1
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:inputText id="inputText1">
                    <f:validator validatorId="customValidator"/>
                    <f:attribute name="inputText2" value="inputText2"/>
                    <f:attribute name="inputText3" value="inputText3"/>
                </h:inputText>
            </rich:column>
        </rich:columnGroup>
        <rich:columnGroup>
            <rich:column>
                inputField2
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:inputText id="inputText2" binding="#{inputText2}"/>
            </rich:column>
        </rich:columnGroup>
    </rich:dataTable>
</ui:composition>
```

### info2.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
    <rich:dataTable id="info2">
        <rich:columnGroup>
            <rich:column>
                inputField3
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:inputText id="inputText3" binding="#{inputText3}"/>
            </rich:column>
        </rich:columnGroup>
    </rich:dataTable>
</ui:composition>
```

### customValidator.java

```
UIInput inputText2Component = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("inputText2");
UIInput inputText3Component = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("inputText3");
//do some validation
inputText2Component.setValid(false);
context.addMessage(inputText2Component.getClientId(), "Validation error message");
inputText3Component.setValid(false);
context.addMessage(inputText3Component.getClientId(), "Validation error message");
if (context.getMessageList().size > 0) {
    context.validationFailed();
    throw new ValidationException(new FacesMessage);
}
```

The problem here is that component from another table `inputText3Component` is not identified properly. `inputText3Component.getClientId()` returns incorrect id, and `inputText3Component.setValid(false)` is not taking effect, and validation message is not displayed, probably because the id is incorrect, however `inputText3Component.getValue()` is exactly what it should be.

`inputText2Component.getClientId()` produces `"form:info1:0:inputText2"`, while
`inputText3Component.getClientId()` produces `"form:info2:inputText3"`. The `:0:` part is omitted for some reason.

Now if I hack into the code like this:

```
inputText3Component.setValid(false);
context.addMessage("form:info2:0:inputText3", "Validation error message");
```

forcing the `:0:` part to be there, then the message is added as it should.

Moreover I don't know, if that is custom validation peculiarity, but `validationFailed()` is not being set for the context. Hence `oncomplete="if (#{!facesContext.validationFailed})displayModal()"` is not working either.

The question is how to get the correct component id and context validation state?